# Extending ApiExplorer using XML Documentation

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've plugged the ASP.Net Web API Help page into one of our projects, but I'm wanting to extend the range of information that's being read from the XML Documentation file.

Specifically, most of our endpoints return resources that, in addition to that resource's data also include a number of `<Link>` elements, which have `rel` and `uri` properties, to link to other resources and endpoints. We've extended the XML documentation to include documentation on what `rel`s may be included in each resource:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the X Resource
/// </summary>
/// <returns>An X</returns>
/// <resources>
/// <resource rel="self">Self reference</resource>
/// <resource rel="related-item1">Description of related item 1</resource>
/// </resources>
```

Great, this all goes into the XML documentation file. However, [`IDocumentationProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.idocumentationprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) only has two methods defined on it - one to return the "documentation" for the method (as a `string`), and one to return the documentation for a parameter (ditto). And it's an implementation of this interface that's currently searching through the XML Documentation.

I *could* try stuffing the extra XML information into this documentation string, alongside the actual documentation, but that feels somewhat ugly. I'd like to extend the interface with a new method to retrieve this more structured data and use it to populate a suitably extended `HelpPageApiModel`. But I'm not sure how best to go about this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the installed file at Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageConfigurationExtension.cs, there is the following method where you could grab the action descriptor of an action and customize the documentation as you need and populate your 'extended' HelpPageApiModel and also as you might know that you would need to modify the HelpPageApiModel.cshtml to take your 'extended' HelpPageApiModel properties if any.

private static HelpPageApiModel GenerateApiModel(ApiDescription apiDescription, HelpPageSampleGenerator sampleGenerator)

Doing customizations in this method is better because a HelpPageApiModel is cached after the first call. So, if you do any customizations in the above method, you automatically gain this caching experience.

Adding an extra method on the IDocumentationProvider isn't going to help as in the end you would be needing to call it yourself somehow as web api framework wouldn't have any knowledge of it.

example of how you could get hold of the action and parameters as below:

```
 private static HelpPageApiModel GenerateApiModel(ApiDescription apiDescription, HelpPageSampleGenerator sampleGenerator)
    {
        HelpPageApiModel apiModel = new HelpPageApiModel();
        apiModel.ApiDescription = apiDescription;

        HttpActionDescriptor currentActionDescriptor = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor;

        IEnumerable<HttpParameterDescriptor> currentActionParamDescriptors = ad.GetParameters();
```

BTW, there is currently a bug where the 'return' documentation of an action is not shown in the help page, but you could fix this by doing some customizations. Yao has some good blogs on help page over **[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/10/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-3-advanced-help-page-customizations.aspx)**.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've done. (I've kept the method that does the XML reading in the documentation provider class, but I just re-obtain the instance from `config.Services` and verify it's the class I think it is).